# Implicit cursor for loop MariaDB doesn't seem to work

Tags: mysql, sql, for-loop, mariadb, procedure

I have to search a table name in my database in which a specified column value exists.
The column name is "Nummer" and i want to give the value as a parameter of the procedure.
The DBMS i use is MariaDB 10.3

My idea was first to select every Table in which the column 'Nummer' exists and then loop through these tables and check if the value exists.
Then i would like to "return" the table name in which the value was found.

I already accomplished to find all tables in which the column "Nummer" exists:

```
select table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'Nummer'
```

Now i thought it would be useful to work with a for loop and loop through every table to search the value:

```
create or replace procedure Forloop (
    in param_nummer int unsigned 
    )
    for i in (select table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'Nummer')
    do 
        -- if exists (select * from i where 'Nummer' = param_nummer);
        -- return i (table_name) ?
    end for;
end//

delimiter;
call forloop();
```

The problem is, when i execute the procedure, it seems like MariaDB does not use the implicit cursur "i" in the select statement.
I got the error "dbName.i" not found, or something like that.
How can i manage to do that?

Comment: You need to use dynamic sql to use a variable as the table name, see e.g. [Dynamic table name at sql statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27542617)

Comment: to add to @Solarflare 's comment watch out for possible SQL injections when using dynamic SQL

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but how can i put the values from "i" (in the for loop) into my variable for the tables? `set @table = i;` does not seem to work

Comment: Is this a one-time task?  If not, then I must admonish you that it is bad schema design to have a value that could be in one of several tables.

Comment: Yes it's just a task for the university. The value could be in several tables, because it's a specialization for one entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is *part* of the code you need:

In your attempt, you do `SELECT table_name ...`.  Instead, of just `table_name`, construct the query you need to execute.  Do this with a messy `CONCAT(...)` (which I will provide below).

```
SELECT CONCAT("select 'table_name', nummer = param_nummer FROM table_name")
         from information_schema.columns
         where column_name = 'nummer'
```

Before the next step, eyeball the output from the select.  It should be a few rows like

```
select 'some_table', nummer = 123 FROM some_table
select 'another_table', nummer = 123 FROM another_table
```

Then you have to `prepare` and `execute` each row found.  This will give you

```
some_table    1
another_table 0
```

Where 1 means true and 0 means false.

OK, now I will fix the CONCAT to make it work.  Keep in mind that sql has *no* way to "interpolate" like many other langauges.  That is, we need to depend entirely on `CONCAT`.

```
SELECT CONCAT("select 'table_name', nummer = param_nummer FROM table_name")
```

-->

```
SELECT CONCAT("select '", table_name, "', nummer = ", param_nummer, " FROM ", table_name)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me alot! After looking up some things about prepared statements and how i could connect the results from the statements in the for-loop it finally worked. I created a temporary table, where i inserted all the results from the for-loop.