# Can I select some information where the table name is a result of concat operation

Tags: mysql

I have to SELECT some data from yesterday's archive of a table. It gets archived in a format : APIOperatorLog_YYYY_MM_DD. But I have to add that select in to a script so that name have to change himself automatically. For that, I used CONCAT operator:

```
SELECT CONCAT("APIOperatorLog_" , DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), "%Y_%m_%d"));
```

That's the output:

```
APIOperatorLog_2022_08_18
```

It's working perfectly.
Now, I have to use that output, instead of table name,
Like, not:

```
SELECT * FROM APIOperatorLog_2022_08_18;
```

Instead, since that date is changing every day, I'd like to do smh like that:

```
SET @tbl_name = CONCAT("APIOperatorLog_" , DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), "%Y_%m_%d"));
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tbl_name;
```

But that's not working, so I also tried this:

```
SET @tbl_name = CONCAT("APIOperatorLog_" , DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), "%Y_%m_%d"));
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT count(*) from ' + @tbl_name;
EXEC @SQLQuery;
```

But that's not working too, any suggestions?

Comment: Here there's probably what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542617/dynamic-table-name-at-sql-statement

Comment: Use dynamic queries

Answer (score 0):

Thank you boiz, that's what I did if someone will need that:

```
SET @tbl = CONCAT('APIOperatorLog_' , DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y_%m_%d')); 
SET @SQLQuery = CONCAT('SELECT count(*) from ' , @tbl, ' WHERE hour(datetime) BETWEEN 9 AND 21 AND requestType = \'RECHARGE\''); 
prepare stmt from @SQLQuery; 
execute stmt;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).